# Why the same images are repeated in all the collection views of iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a table view where am listing some set of images from the XML file which is retrieved as URL. I extended this with Collection Views where when user selects the image in table view corresponding image will take to next window displaying some set of images as collection view.

Here i face a problem as when i click any image in table view it displays the same images for all collection views. For better understanding i attached the image below,

[image: Collection Images]

In this, the table view shows Image-1,Image-2... and so on. When i click the Image-1 in table view the collection view displays as Image1-1,Image1-2,.. and so on. Again when i click the Image-2 in table view it again shows the same Image-1-1, Image-1-2 ...and so on.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem,

The corresponding code are shown below,

**The tableView**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     xmlParser = [[myXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://sample.com/Images.xml"];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
   }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
     return 1;
   }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
     return [xmlParser.tweets count];
   }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"images";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *tweetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
    tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
    [cell setBackgroundView:tweetImageView];
    return cell;
  }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  MyCollectionViewController *collectViewController = [[MyCollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detail" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:collectViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**The CollectionView**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      xmlParser = [[myXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://sample.com/Images.xml"];
      UIImage *currentImage = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:0];
      customimage.image = currentImage;
      UIImage *currentImage1 = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1];
      customimage1.image = currentImage1;
    }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
   {
     return 1;
   }

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return [xmlParser.tweets count];
  }

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *tweetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,myCell.frame.size.width , myCell.frame.size.height)]; 
    tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
    [myCell setBackgroundView:tweetImageView];
    return myCell;
 }
```

**UPDATED**

**MY XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
<products id="0">
 <img>http://myimage.com/images/logo1.png</img>
</products>
 <products id="1">
 <img>http://myimage.com/images/Main_pic.png</img>
</products>
<products id="2">
<img>http://myimage.com/images/image1.png</img>
</products>
<products id="3">
<img>http://myimage.com/images/image2.png</img>
<img-subproduct>http://myimage.com/images/image2-1.png</img-subproduct>
<img-subproduct>http://myimage.com/images/image2-2.png</img-subproduct>
</products>
<products id="4">
<img>http://myimage.com/images/image3.png</img>
<img-subproduct>http://myimage.com/images/image3-1.png</img-subproduct>
<img-subproduct>http://myimage.com/images/image3-2.png</img-subproduct>
</products>
</Products>
```

Comment: Whether u click on Image-1 or Image-2 or Image-3 etc... and you push your next collection View screen  you always see same set of images (i.e the collection of images which belong to Image-1 are shown for Image-2 also instead of its own collection of images). 
   Am i Right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use storyboard, MyCollectionViewCell will always load from stroyboard.

So, change MyCollectionViewCell interface:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tweetImageView;
@end
```

And link the property in stroryboard.

---

Well, I write that for you.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!myCell) {
        myCell = [[MyCollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,myCell.frame.size.width , myCell.frame.size.height)];
    }
    [myCell.tweetImageView setImage:[[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return myCell;
}
```

And MyCollectionViewCell interface and implementation:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *tweetImageView;
@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIImageView *aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        aImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [self addSubview:aImageView];
        self.tweetImageView = aImageView;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

You set currentTweet to `[[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`?

I think it's nil. Check it.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *tweetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,myCell.frame.size.width , myCell.frame.size.height)]; 
    tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
    NSLog(@"%@", tweetImageView.image);         // Check tweetImageView.image whether nil or not.
    [myCell setBackgroundView:tweetImageView];
    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: No the log shows the values as `<UIImage: 0x75bb310> <UIImage: 0x75c39f0>
<UIImage: 0x75be700>
 <UIImage: 0x75c7ee0>
 <UIImage: 0x7571280>
 <UIImage: 0x75cbd10>`

Comment: Have you add custom backgroundView to MyCollectionViewCell? It's nil by default.

Comment: I tried like this, `UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` `UIImage * image = selectedCell.image;` `subproductimage.image = image;` here `subproductimage` is `UIImageView` but it shows a warning  `'image' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 3.0` and this doesnt change anything.

Comment: I tried with your code getting an error `-[UICollectionViewCell tweetImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75749c0` `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell tweetImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75749c0'
` FYI now am not getting collection view window

Comment: Your MyCollectionViewCell load from storyboard? Change the cell class to MyCollectionViewCell.

Comment: ya am using storyboard i cleared that error as you said now i can view the collection view but it shows blank without any images. I think its not parsing i wrote parsing in `MyCollectionViewController`. Do i need to write the parsing code in `MyCollectionViewCell`

Comment: Sorry i just seen the edited answer when i connect the `IBOutlet` it shows the images but those again shows as previous problem what i asked in question.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When you click on any row of the tableview (say Image-2) then above mentioned method gets called.

Inside this method you call ::: pushViewController which pushes the collection view class

After this Collection View gets loaded ::: Now tell me how will the view did load method collection view class will understand that its has to show the images corresponding to Image-2

For this when u call pushviewController you should also pass some argument, depending on which you should fetch its corresponding collection and show them.

**Update :**

To fetch Image when user clicks on table view:

```
UIImage *selectedIamge = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If user clicked first row then indexpath.row = 0
and inside this array >> [xmlParser tweets] >> the image at zero index is the one dat u need.
In this way u can get the image.

Its not necessary that u fetch the image applied on the tableview cell, instead u can fetch the image from the array from which tableview cells are insitialized.

Comment: ya i understood it but when i use the selected image to identify by collection view like this , `UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` `UIImage * image = selectedCell.image;` `subproductimage.image = image;` here `subproductimage`is UIImageView but it shows a warning `'image' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 3.0` and this doesnt change anything.

Comment: I tried your update swati its not working for me. Can you check my XML file which i had updated. The `img-subproduct` are the one which i need to show in collection views

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
UIImageView *tweetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
```

To :

```
UIImageView *tweetImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)]autorelease];
```

Comment: But rushi as am using ARC,  `autorelease` is unavailable.

Comment: Oops.. When i was doing the same thing in one of my project the same issue was solved by autorelease. If you can exclude this one class from ARC and try the autorelease. If it doesn't work you can again add the class in ARC.

Comment: No change rushi, its same as before